# Data source name not found and no default driver specified nodejs

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I was deploying my code from local to web server(Windows 2012).

I am getting the following error.

> Error { ConnectionError: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified at msnodesql.open (c:\apps\vim\node_modules\mssql\lib\msnodesqlv8.js:174:17)

My Code:

```
function ConnectToSql() {

  var sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
  var config = {
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    connectionString: 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=xxxxx;Database=xxxx;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
  };
  const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
      return pool.request().query("select 1 as number")
      }).then(result => {
        sql.close();
      }).catch(err => {
        sql.close();
      });

}
```

I have setup a DSN connection and it is working fine from within in the WebServer.

Comment: Does SQL Server allow external connections?  Ports open in the Firewall?

Comment: @Grantly, yes i was able to establish the connection from my local system. The database server is remote.

Comment: Have you port forwarded your SQL port (i think 1433, 1434, 432 - look them up too ) from  your switch / hub / router to  your server firewall and opened the ports?

Answer (score 1):

The Driver name was incorrect. It needs to match the name that shows inside DSN.